# How to show opened page tap in navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html

I have code in which , I want to show opened page navigation page tap,I want to highlight the tap link according to page whichever opened .

But, Now when click on come link in this navigation bar, then page reloads and displaying only main page UL opened .

I want to perform , when user click on some link that link box UL needs to be displayed . Below is my code

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div class="box">
<div class="h_title">&#8250; <b>Home</b></div>
<ul id="home">
<li class="b1"><a class="icon page" href="/portal/">Status</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
<div class="h_title">&#8250; <b>About Us</b></div>
<ul>
<li class="b1"><a class="icon page" href="">Custom Report</a></li>
<li class="b1"><a class="icon page" href="">History Log</a></li>
<li class="b1"><a class="icon page" href="">Graphs</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
<div class="h_title">&#8250; <b>PROFILES</b></div>
<ul>
<li class="b1"><a class="icon page" href="">Filters</a></li>
<li class="b1"><a class="icon page" href="">StaffList</a></li>
<li class="b1"><a class="icon page" href="">StudentList</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
<div class="h_title">&#8250; <b>ADMINISTRATION</b></div>
<ul>
<li class="b1"><a class="icon page" href="">Manage Licenses</a></li>
<li class="b1"><a class="icon page" href="">Change Password</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
   $(".box .h_title").not(this).next("ul").hide("normal");
   $(".box .h_title").not(this).next("#home").show("normal");
   $(".box").children(".h_title").click( function() { $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(); });
  });
</script>
```

Thank You
Pervez

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you want a tap navigation. You do not need  to reinvent the wheel. Try jquery ui tap navigation:

**jQuery UI Tabs** http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Thank You for your fast response . Actually I Just want to highlight those links whichever is clicked and opened the page . I want to display that BOX and there sub-links.